# Wait until object is not null to execute my if condition Java

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two methods, both using the same object.

```
Object A;

public void methodA() {
    //Client code talks to server, create data, and instantiate A. 
    A = new A();
}

public void methodB() {
    if(A!=null) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This is a simplified logic to what I'm trying to achieve, but at the moment I'm instantiating **Object A** in method A, my app is talking to the server and creating data for that object and when my app is executing **methodB()**, **ObjectA** is null.

Another catch is that when I'm debugging my app, the **ObjectA** has an instance and methodB() is executed properly because debugging is a slower process, however, when I'm running it, ObjectA is returning as null. I tried to use notify and wait, but I'm not able to set my objectA in a synchronized block because it's returning an null so my app is crashing.

---

**EDIT: Adding my current code:**

```
//Firebase Authentication
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
//Database reference
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public void methodA() {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            getUserEmailAddress(), getUserPassword())
            .addOnCompleteListener(ActivityA.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword: onComplete" + task.isSuccessful());
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityA.this, "authentication failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void methodB() {
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userInformation);
    }
}
```

**mAuth.getCurrentUser()** is returning null because methodB is executing before the server is creating a firebaseUser instance.

Comment: Is it really as you show here, where methodA instantiates A, or is A instantiated in some async method when the server responds?

Comment: @JemarJones so the server creates a userId and that is my object. I illustrated that by putting a `A = new A();`, but that is actually happening on the server side.

Comment: I think we need to see something much more detailed to help you determine the best solution here

Comment: @JemarJones Added my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing your actual situation, i believe the wait/notify method shown in other answers isn't the best solution for your case.

It seems the fundamental problem you have here is that you need to perform some action only once a user is signed in/authenticated. This is a classic case of attempting to perform a synchronous action with an object that you obtain in an asynchronous manner. The general best practice for those situations is only performing the action once you get a result from your async action, using a callback. A great solution here is to use the callbacks that Firebase provides for change of authentication state. From the docs:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

From here you can determine your logic for calling methodB (depends on your specific use case).

Comment: @EJP I already have `mAuthListener` listener in my onCreate method in my activity. Please see my reply to Frank.

Comment: @RedaM This is my answer actually. I'm not understanding how you're experiencing the issue you describe. If you are indeed waiting for one of the auth callbacks before you run whichever code you intend to (methodB i assume), then you shouldn't be experiencing any issue involving the null object.

Comment: I realized that I used the wrong object in the wrong place from your suggestion but yours works absolutely fine ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

As often the case with asynchronous code, the solution is to reframe the problem from "first get A, then do B" to "start A, then when A is done do B".

```
public void createUserAndSaveToDatabase() {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getUserEmailAddress(), getUserPassword())
         .addOnCompleteListener(ActivityA.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                     databaseReference
                         .child(user.getUid())
                         .setValue(...);
                 }
             }
         });
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. Whenever it's the complete first time I'm running my app, the authentication is getting created in firebase console, but the token of the realtime database is not showing until I re run my app for a second time and then after that everything works fine. I thought about blocking the thread until the object is not null anymore, hence my first question (wait and notify).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `wait()/notify()`, although there are higher-level techniques as well:

```
public synchronised void methodA()
{
    // ...
    a = new A();
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronised void methodB()
{
    while (a == null)
    {
        wait();
    }
    // do something
}
```

Can't understand your statement about trying to use wait & notify.

Comment: thanks for replying. Are higher-level techniques best practices or do you suggest wait and notify as far as my scenario?

Comment: Whatever you like. This will work. There is really no such thing as 'best practice', only what is appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
Object A;

public synchronized void methodA() {
    //Client code talks to server, create data, and instantiate A. 
    A = new A();
    this.notify();
};

public synchronized void methodB() {

    while (A==null) {
        this.wait();
    }

    // do something
}
```